# Create a VSFTPD server with anonymous access

Tags: 14.04, server, ftp

I want to set up a FTP server on Ubuntu 14.04 I have full access to the server and any tutorial I find online doesn't tell me exactly how to access it.

I am using VSFTPD because of many suggestions.

However it still doesn't quite answer the question of using an FTP for server access, as in it should allow anonymous people to download from it.

Any help would be appreciated

(My friend's FTP website he bought)
http://uje.dev9.org/etmain/

This would be an example of something I want to set up.
Anything even close to this would work, I just want to be able to anonymously download from it.

**EDIT**

Changed some settings because of another askubuntu thread.

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=NO
write_enable=NO
anon_root=/srv/ftp
anon_max_rate=2048000
xferlog_enable=YES
listen=YES
```

My last issue I have is that, even when I try to connect anonymously, it still asks me for a password. How do I fix that?

My config is:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=YES

anon_root=/src/ftp

anon_max_rate=2048000
#
# Run standalone with IPv6?
# Like the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6 socket
# instead of an IPv4 one. This parameter and the listen parameter are mutually
# exclusive.
#listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default)
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=NO
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
ferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
# This option specifies the location of the RSA key to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your config:

```
no_anon_password=YES
```

From vsftpd.conf(5):

```
   no_anon_password
          When enabled, this prevents vsftpd from asking for an anonymous password - the anonymous user will
          log straight in.

          Default: NO
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer vsftpd in Ubuntu. They have a guide with the anonymous access configuration. This is taken from https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html

By default vsftpd is configured to only allow anonymous download. During installation a ftp user is created with a home directory of /home/ftp. This is the default FTP directory.

If you wish to change this location, to /srv/ftp for example, simply create a directory in another location and change the ftp user's home directory:

```
sudo mkdir /srv/ftp
sudo usermod -d /srv/ftp ftp
```

After making the change restart vsftpd:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Finally, copy any files and directories you would like to make available through anonymous FTP to /srv/ftp.

Comment: I didn't have a 'vsftpd' inside of /init.d/ however I had a 'vsftpd.conf' file inside of /etc/ I changed some of the settings in it to match another post here on askubuntu. However the last problem I have is that, it still asks for password even if I try to connect anonymously.

Comment: Check out /var/log/vsftpd.log what the error is, also please share your config. :)

Comment: It is uploaded now. And I do not have that directory or that log file.

Comment: Try reinstalling vsftpd -  `sudo aptitude reinstall vsftpd`. Also restarting vsftpd - `sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`.

Comment: It says '/etc/init.d/vsftpd: command not found'